# Unpacking a JSONField into multiple django form fields

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I am using a JSONField from django.contrib.postgres.fields in my Django model. I want to set up my update form so that it looks at the object being passed into it, iterates through the JSON from the JSONfield, and dynamically creates the right amount of CharFields.

models.py:

```
class myclass(models.Model):
    purpose_section = JSONField()
```

forms.py:

```
class myclassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myclass
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in self.fields['purpose_section'].initial:
            self.fields['purpose_section_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label="purpose_section_" + i,value=i.content)
```

When I try to access the page, I receive an error: 
'NoneType' object is not iterable

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what view you're using, but assuming it's a view that'll pass the instance of the DB row you're trying to edit (such as UpdateView with a url that passes the pk to it),

You can try this in your form:

```
for key in self.instance.purpose_section:
   self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(label=key, max_length=256)
   self.fields[key].initial = self.instance.purpose_section[key]
```

If you're not using a view that does that, you'll need to pass the instance yourself.